# Why is it discouraged to use Resources.getIdentifier()

Tags: android

In the Android SDK, there is a comment that says it's more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier instead of by name.

Is this the only reason it's discouraged to use getIdentifier()?

I need to programmatically access one of several hundred resources and so far my design makes it easier to access raw resources by name instead of identifier.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037643/12272687

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because comparing integers is much faster than comparing strings and I would guess that the resources are hashed by their ID, so if you get a resource by ID they can grab only a small subset of resources and perform a fast search.  If you search by name they'd have to iterate through all the resources and do a slow string compare.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, getIdentifier() is slower/less efficient than just retrieving the resource by ID, I think it uses reflection to get the identifier from the generated R class. But I'm not aware of any other reason not to use it... Look into [array resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray), maybe you can use those instead.